# Emacs: how to make abbrevs work in python comments?

Tags: python, emacs, comments, abbreviation, python-mode

I'm trying to use abbrev-mode in python-mode.
Abbrevs work fine in python code but doesn't work in python comments. 
How can I make them work in python comments too?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875741/emacs-abbrev-mode-cant-work-in-python-mode

Comment: I don't think that's duplicate because in my case abbrevs work globally in python-mode totally and the problem is not related to underscores in the identifiers (there are no underscores there).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this was a bug in python.el and has been fixed in more recent versions.  Not sure if the fix is in 24.3 or in 24.4.
If it's still in the 24.4 pretest, please report it as a bug.